# XYZ coordinates to XY Grids

Tags: r, performance

I have a list of XY coordinates for fixed positions with given Z values that I want to efficiently fill into an XY grid.

Example code:

```
x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5)
y = c(1,2,3,2,4,3,5,5)
z = rep(10,8)

grid = matrix(NA, nrow = max(x), ncol = max(y))
              
#fill the grid for given combinations of X and Y with Z values
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  grid[x[i],y[i]] = z[i]
}

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   10   NA   10   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   10   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
```

Is there a more efficient way to fill the grid instead of using for-loops?

I tried `grid[x,y] = z` but that didn't work.

Comment: The coordinates (x,y)=(2,2) happens two times in your example. What to do in those cases?

Comment: My apologies, that shouldn't happen. It was simply a typo in my example. I'll edit it quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a dataframe with the coordinates to use that to assign these values to your matrix use the following code:

```r
x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5)
y = c(1,2,3,2,2,3,5,5)
z = rep(10,8)

# Create dataframe of coordinates
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
# Convert to matrix
df.mat <- as.matrix(df)
grid = matrix(NA, nrow = max(x), ncol = max(y))

grid[df.mat] <- z
grid
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]   10   10   10   NA   NA
#> [2,]   NA   10   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA   10   NA   NA
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful! So, basically instead of `grid[x,y] = z` all I had to do was `grid[cbind(x,y)] = z`. I was hoping there was an elegant solution like that :-)

Comment: Or simply do `grid[cbind(x,y)]<- z`

Answer (score 1):

Behold the beauty of `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) { grid[x, y] <<- z }, x, y, z)

grid
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   10   10   10   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   10   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   10   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
```